# How to copy Discovery rules from one templates to another in zabbix

Tags: templates, monitoring, zabbix

How to **copy** the **discovery rules** from one template to another like items and triggers to another template?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported currently. You might want to vote on the [feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1783).

If there are many of those, you could look into exporting them to XML, hacking the XML and importing it. This would not be a supported approach and you would be on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Export the template. Use a text editor to find and replace every occurrence of the template name in the exported xml file with the name of the template you'd like to create. Then, import it.

Comment: For example, the compute nodes in my clusters are under heavy IO at all times. I was getting constant notifications about it. Instead of editing the trigger for iowait > 20 in hundreds of clients, I exported 'Template OS Linux' and used sed to replace 'Template OS Linux' with 'Template OS Linux - Compute Nodes'. Then, I imported the template, changed the trigger threshold, unlinked 'Template OS Linux' from all the compute nodes, and linked them to 'Template OS Linux - Compute Nodes'.